# Is it possible to force rebuild previous view of a Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a table view in my previous view which is get data from an array in my app. I have a view to update data which is push on cell select. Once data is updated in the view i call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to go back to previous view. But the label get stacked with old and new data I don't know why... If I go one view back and come back again to the tableview everything is fine only new data is shown..

So I guess I have to rebuild view to avoid the problem. Is this possible ?

Comment: I have a table view in my previous view which is get data from an array in my app. I have a view to update data which is push on cell select. Once data is updated in the view i call  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to go back to previous view. But the label get stacked with old and new data I don't know why... If I go one view back and come back again to the tableview everything is fine only new data is shown..

Comment: Please, edit your question and add it there. Thanks.

Comment: "the label get stacked with old and new data I don't know why" this is the problem you need to solve.  Please post screenshots and source code related to this label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question initially asked about rebuilding a controller, so here's the answer to that:

---

I'm assuming that your have a navigation stack like this:

- An instance of `FirstController`
- An instance of `SecondController`
- An instance of `ThirdController`

A thing happens in your third controller, and you now want the stack to look like this:

- An instance of `FirstController`
- A new instance of `SecondController`

The first thing to do is to define a delegate protocol for `ThirdController`, in your header file like this:

```
@protocol ThirdControllerDelegate;

@class ThirdController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ThirdControllerDelegate> delegate;

... your existing stuff ...

@end

@protocol ThirdControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)thirdControllerDidDoTheThing:(ThirdController *)thirdController;

@end
```

Instead of having the `ThirdController` pop itself, it should tell its delegate that the thing happened, like so:

```
[self.delegate thirdControllerDidDoTheThing:self];
```

You'll also want to define a delegate protocol for `SecondController`, in the same way, and you'll want to specify that `SecondController` can act as a delegate for a `ThirdController`:

```
#import "ThirdController.h"

@protocol SecondControllerDelegate;

@class SecondController : UIViewController <ThirdControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SecondControllerDelegate> delegate;

... your existing stuff ...

@end

@protocol SecondControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)secondControllerDidDoTheThing:(SecondController *)secondController;

@end
```

Notice the extra bit in there where we put `<ThirdControllerDelegate>` after the `@class` line.

Now we find the part of the `SecondController` that shows the `ThirdController`, and have it set the controller's delegate first:

```
- (void)showThirdControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    ThirdController *thirdController = [[ThirdController alloc] init];
    thirdController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdController animated:animated];
}
```

When the `SecondController` gets the message from the `ThirdController`, it should pass it on to its delegate, like this:

```
- (void)thirdControllerDidDoTheThing:(ThirdController *)thirdController
{
    [self.delegate secondControllerDidDoTheThing:self];
}
```

Finally we modify `FirstController` so that it can act as the delegate to the `SecondController`:

```
#import "SecondController."

@class FirstController : UIViewController <SecondControllerDelegate>
```

When we show the `SecondController`, we make the `FirstController` its delegate:

```
- (void)showSecondControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    SecondController *secondController = [[SecondController alloc] init];
    secondController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:animated];
}
```

Finally we implement the `SecondController`'s delegate method to pop to the first controller, then show a new secondController.

```
- (void)secondControllerDidDoTheThing:(SecondController *)secondController
{
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:self animated:NO];
    [self showSecondControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Done.

---

You've since altered your question; in the case you now describe you can follow the steps above to make the `SecondController` the delegate of the `ThirdController`, but then inside `thirdControllerDidDoTheThing` you just reload the data of your `SecondController`'s view; if it's a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` you'd do that with the `reloadData` method.

Comment: Seems like a good solution I will implement this an check the result

Answer (score 0):

you should refresh your table view every time it is going to be shown; otherwise, the old data would be cached.

In the controller that controls the table view:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```